# Analog Delay, guitar pedals, time measurement

Tags: guitar-effects

I have noticed that analog delay pedals for guitar do not have a time measurement in msec or anything. It is just a knob.

Why is this done? Have I missed a brand that has a measurement?
Many may have a tap tempo..

In digital delay pedals, it makes more sense?

Comment: Not all digital delays are marked in ms (see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_(audio_effect)#mediaviewer/File:Ibanez_de7.jpg which has a range switch such that permanent markings don't make sense). Analog delays tend to be more variable (due to component tolerances), so it's harder to be precise about the timings, too.

Comment: ok, yes I know about the digital delays, I just hadnt understood why there is nothing on analog delays

Comment: why dont you post this as an answer?

Comment: Clock timing on (older) analogue synths was notoriously variable, meaning they went out of tune as they got warmer. I'd guess older analogue delays use similar technology meaning it's hard to be precise about the milliseconds delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the primary reason analog delays tend not to be marked in ms is that, due to the way they're implemented and the tolerances of the components involved, it's difficult to be precise about the timings. Providing these markings implies a level of precision that the circuitry is unlikely to achieve.

Note also that not all digital delays are marked in ms; for example, the Ibanez DE7:

[image: Ibanez DE7 digital delay]

This pedal has a delay Range switch, so permanent markings don't make sense, and the Delay Time knob is simply marked 0-10.